# Let $ψ:A\to B$ is a group homomorphism , then can i say ψ is injective iff kerψ={e1}

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I don't know my assumption is true or not.But one part is easy i.e. when ψ is injective then kerψ contain the identity of A . But another part i am stuck. Even i can't find any counter example
Here e1 and e2 are identity element of A and B respectively.

Comment: Your supposition is correct, this is a standard result.  To see the converse, take $\psi(a) = \psi(b)$, then via properties of group homomorphisms $\psi(ab^{-1}) = e_2$, meaning that $ab^{-1} \in \text{ker}(\psi)$.

Comment: This is an FAQ.